# SQL Server Monitor Data Inserts, Updates and Deletes from Legacy Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

We currently have a legacy desktop application that uses SQL Server 2014 as the database.  We would like to add some additional features outside of the software which we don't have the source code to.

How can we monitor what data is inserted, updated or deleted to different tables in the database when a certain task is completed in the desktop software?  This would allow us to add data to the database in the same way that the desktop application is currently doing it.

We have tried SQL Profiler but can't seem to get the information.

Is there a way to get a differential between two points in time from one database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the trigger which are executed automatically in response to Create,Update,Delete.you can create the triggers for each table and it will give you the required information

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name
ON table_name
AFTER  {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]}
[NOT FOR REPLICATION]
AS
{sql_statements}
```

Comment: what if he has 2000 tables? if he creates triggers for ALL his tables then he's exactly where he started in the first place

Comment: Yes, this is an issue.  The database has around 500 tables and we aren't sure which tables are being hit by each function in the application.

Comment: We are doing this on a test database so is there a way to add a trigger to every table without having to do it one table at a time and that all the triggers would add records to one table where we can see the different actions?

Comment: as far as i am aware that A trigger (insert, Update, and/or Delete) belongs to a particular table.  If you need a trigger on two tables (or many tables) you will need two triggers (or many triggers)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant is there a way to add one trigger to every table with a script as opposed to adding one trigger at a time.

Comment: @rubendn Please don't do this. Identify the tables that are modified and just create a trigger for them. And sure you can create a trigger for every table but what are they going to do anyways? U will also have to fill them with some kind of logic and if you don't have 500 identical tables then there's no use to that.

Comment: @Xaphas I understand and wouldn't do this on a live database but this response lead me in the right direction to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166618/adding-trigger-to-sql-tables  which gives me exactly what I'm looking for. It adds a trigger to each table with one script and It gives me 1 audit table with each table a change was made to as well as old value and new value.  I'm not going to be using the test database going forward so it's not going to affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
We have tried SQL Profiler but can't seem to get the information
```

^ This is the correct course of action. Triggers will only show you the end result of queries, not what queries are actually run - there may be calculations, intermediate steps etc.

When you say you 'can't seem to get the information', what exactly do you mean? Profiler will be able to show you the text of all queries ran against the SQL Instance

Comment: It's probably because I'm not using the right filters to narrow it down but I was getting couple of thousand lines in profiler for just one insert action in the legacy app.  What we are concerned with mainly is what is changing in the database so using triggers it is showing us exactly what was inserted, changed or deleted.  We don't necessarily need the actual queries used.